# AWS Athena identify malformed CSVs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to combine CSVs which I created and put into S3 into a single CSV file. I am using AWS Athena queries to do that, but I'm getting errors like

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing column '0': For input string: apples</li><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><div class=""atlanta"">organges</div> ...
```

How do I solve this?

This is my code - the `description` field/column contains HTML.

Creating table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default`.`my_table` (
  `item_no` double,
  `description` string, 
  `name` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://my_location/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Querying table:

```
select * from my_table
where "item_no" < 30000
limit 10
```

Comment: Does that HTML snippet appear in side one of your files? Do a search of the files to try and find those words and you'll likely find the cause of the error.

Comment: Yes but I can't really search them because they are in S3. I believe the issue is I'm not sure how many malformed CSVs there are, because I can't identify them.

Comment: You'll likely need to download them somewhere and then search the contents.